# Identify the headings in a JSON with pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I Have this JSON File

```
*[
  {
    "name": "Kitty",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["fresh food"],
      "dislikes": ["stale food"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Pupster",
    "species" : "dog",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["tomatoes", "peas"],
      "dislikes": ["bread"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Tux",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["fancy dishes"],
      "dislikes": ["basic cat food"]
    }
  }
]*
```

---

I read this file in this way:

```
    content = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/animals-3.json") 
data = json.loads(content.content)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

But what I want is to read only the JSON file headers and store them in a list. I have this code that does a similar function

```
 getcolumns = list(df.columns.values)
```

but I only get the following

- name
- species
- foods

And what I want to achieve is the following:

- name
- species
- foods
- likes
- dislikes

I am new using Pandas, any suggestion is accepted

Comment: 'likes' and 'dislikes' are under the 'foods' category, if you further split out those 2, then there would be nothing in the 'foods' column. the table would contain 'name', 'species', 'likes' and 'dislikes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list comprehension should work:

```
j = [
  {
    "name": "Kitty",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["fresh food"],
      "dislikes": ["stale food"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Pupster",
    "species" : "dog",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["tomatoes", "peas"],
      "dislikes": ["bread"]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Tux",
    "species" : "cat",
    "foods": {
      "likes": ["fancy dishes"],
      "dislikes": ["basic cat food"]
    }
  }
]

getcolumns = [x for x in j[0]] + [x for x in j[0]['foods']]
# ['name', 'species', 'foods', 'likes', 'dislikes']
```

or if you want a dataframe:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(j)

     foods.dislikes       foods.likes     name species
0      [stale food]      [fresh food]    Kitty     cat
1           [bread]  [tomatoes, peas]  Pupster     dog
2  [basic cat food]    [fancy dishes]      Tux     cat
```